# how to change this json to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
json= {'name': 'system_information', 'url': 'https://gbfs.divvybikes.com/gbfs/en/system_information.json'}
{'name': 'station_information', 'url': 'https://gbfs.divvybikes.com/gbfs/en/station_information.json'}
{'name': 'station_status', 'url': 'https://gbfs.divvybikes.com/gbfs/en/station_status.json'}
{'name': 'free_bike_status', 'url': 'https://gbfs.divvybikes.com/gbfs/en/free_bike_status.json'}
{'name': 'system_hours', 'url': 'https://gbfs.divvybikes.com/gbfs/en/system_hours.json'}
{'name': 'system_calendar', 'url': 'https://gbfs.divvybikes.com/gbfs/en/system_calendar.json'}
{'name': 'system_regions', 'url': 'https://gbfs.divvybikes.com/gbfs/en/system_regions.json'}
{'name': 'system_alerts', 'url': 'https://gbfs.divvybikes.com/gbfs/en/system_alerts.json'}
```

and I want transform this json to dataframe.

How to do with it?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([json])
df = pd.concat([df])
df.reset_index(drop=True)
print(data_unit)
```

This do not work.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to convert the variable `json` to a dataframe, or that you want to fetch each URL, and convert those to dataframes?

Comment: Please check your json. The structure is corrupted - it's not a valid code...
The output of json variable is: {'name': 'system_information', 'url': 'https://gbfs.divvybikes.com/gbfs/en/system_information.json'}

So check if it's a real json or list of dicts

Answer (score 0):

JSON is Java Script Object Notation which is not terribly similar to the way Pandas stores data. For that reason, if you want to manipulate JSON objects in python it often helps to 'flatten' them through the use of `pd.json_normalize`. If you have a single JSON object you can simply enclose it in curly brackets as you have, but to create a list of JSON objects you must add square brackets around the entire collection and separate each JSON object with a comma. If `pd.json_normalize` throws an AttributeError it is likely that you need to update you Pandas package.

```
json= [{'name': 'system_information', 'url': 'https://gbfs.divvybikes.com/gbfs/en/system_information.json'},
       {'name': 'station_information', 'url': 'https://gbfs.divvybikes.com/gbfs/en/station_information.json'},
       {'name': 'station_status', 'url': 'https://gbfs.divvybikes.com/gbfs/en/station_status.json'},
       {'name': 'free_bike_status', 'url': 'https://gbfs.divvybikes.com/gbfs/en/free_bike_status.json'},
       {'name': 'system_hours', 'url': 'https://gbfs.divvybikes.com/gbfs/en/system_hours.json'},
       {'name': 'system_calendar', 'url': 'https://gbfs.divvybikes.com/gbfs/en/system_calendar.json'},
       {'name': 'system_regions', 'url': 'https://gbfs.divvybikes.com/gbfs/en/system_regions.json'},
       {'name': 'system_alerts', 'url': 'https://gbfs.divvybikes.com/gbfs/en/system_alerts.json'}]

df = pd.json_normalize(json)
print(df)
```

Comment: Better to provide some description on why you changed their json, and what you're trying to achieve using `json_normalize`